# How to make TFS include bin and debug folders by default

Tags: tfs

I recently started working on a project that is using .Net Core & React. Our shop is using TFS for a version control and this is where I encountered a problem. 
When React project is created it uses NPM that loads up a bunch of files in "node_modules" folder as dependencies. Some of these modules have "bin" and "debug" folders in them, but TFS naturally ignores them causing compilation issues for other developers.

Is there a way to add something like "!\ClientApp\node_modules*" to ".tfignore" file to eliminate this behavior on certain paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all folders generated by package managers from source control entirely. Restoring packages should be part of your build process, both on your desktop and during CI.